# ANTLR - Checking for a String's "contruction"

Tags: antlr, antlr4

Currently working with ANTLR and found out something interesting that's not working as I intended.

I try to run something along the lines of "test 10 cm" through my grammar and it fails, however "test 10 c m" works as the previous should. The "cm" portion of the code is what I call "wholeunit" in my grammar and it is as follows:

```
wholeunit   :
              siunit
            | unitmod siunit
            | wholeunit NUM
            | wholeunit '/' wholeunit
            | wholeunit '.' wholeunit
            ;
```

What it's doing right now is the "unitmod siunit" portion of the rule where unitmod = c and siunit = m . 
What I'd like to know is how would I make it so the grammar would still follow the rule "unitmod siunit" without the need for a space in the middle, I might be missing something huge. (Yes, I have spaces and tabs marked to be skipped)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Probable cause is "cm" being considered another token together (possibly same token type as "test"), rather than "c" and "m" as separate tokens.

Remember that in ANTLR lexer, the rule matching the longest input wins.

One solution would possibly be to make the `wholeunit` a lexer rule rather than parser rule, and make sure it's above the rule that matches any word (like "test") - if same input can be matched by multiple rules, ANTLR selects the first rule in order they're defined in.

Comment: I've tried changing it to a lexer rule yet it doesn't work. The only way I could think of it working is by making siunit and unitmod be lexer rules but then there's the issue of the input being "mm".

Comment: Sure, a lexer rule cannot reference a parser rule, they'd all have to be lexer rules. If `siunit` and `unitmod` were a *fragment* lexer rules, the mm case might still work. Or consider resolving this issue only after parsing, i.e. parse units as a common "word" and then check after parsing is done that it is allowed unit name.